# use-effect doesnt work, only after refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, use-effect

I have problem with useEffect in my React App. I try to translate placeholder in input with useEffect, this is my code:

```
const [age, setAge] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.myLanguage[7] == "p") {
      setAge("Translate One");
    } else {
      setAge("Translate Two");
    }
  });
```

and this is my input:

```
<input
   onChange={handleChangeAge}
   value={titleAge}
   type="number"
   min="1"
   max="100"
   id="age"
   placeholder={age}
   name="age"
   required
></input>
```

This works, because in localstorage it changes, but on page if i want see changes i must refresh page. I need this works after when user switch language in selector. 
Can you help me?

Comment: why don't you use just use react-int

Comment: because i want avoid use that and i need this idea.. it works before, but when i change something it stops works and when i come back to this version it stop works.. and i search solution..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
if (localStorage.myLanguage[7] == "p") {
  setAge("Translate One");
} else {
  setAge("Translate Two");
}
  }, [localStorage.myLanguage]);
```

Which should run every time the array localStorage.myLanguage changes. Let me know if it works since I have not tried it with your code of course. 
If it throws an error saying that the length has changed then do this:

```
[localStorage.myLanguage.join(',')]
```

Comment: It doesnt work, is a same problem, doesnt change placeholder translates when I select language in my selector. :(

Comment: When is useEffect being called here?